# Why my IF don't work correctly?

Tags: validation, batch-file, request, ip, dhcp

I've this script to validate ip request from my DHCP server

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "tokens=2 delims=:" %%a in ('dhcptest-0.5-win64.exe --query --quiet ^| findstr "10.16.100.254"') do if %%a equ 10.16.100.254 (@echo DHCP Working) else (@echo Dhcp server not working!!)

C:\Users\duchoa>Dhcp server not working!
```

But my variable %%a is equal to 10.16.100.254

Can anyone help me please?

Comment: What is the output of `echo %%a` if you use that instead of the `if` statement?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the purpose of a `For` loop:

```dos
@("PathTo\dhcptest-0.5-win64.exe" --query --quiet | Find "10.16.100.254">Nul) && (Echo=DHCP working) || Echo=DHCP Server not working
@Timeout -1
```

Answer (score 0):

Oh my gosh SPACE at "delims=:" trolled me, now working with delims=: "

Thanks all :D